# Installed Ubuntu 11.10, and networking constantly fails

Tags: 11.10, drivers, 64-bit, ethernet

I just installed Ocelot on my new machine (with an ASUS M5A99X EVO motherboard and on-board gigabit ethernet), and I asked it to download updates while it installed. The install took forever, the longest part being the download of updates, which should have been my first clue. Post install, accessing the internet is sketchy at best, but mostly just broken. The adapter consistently fails to pull down down an ip address or the DNS addresses from my router.

I should also note that I know this isn't a hardware problem, because I can boot into Windows 7 (dual boot), and the ethernet works just fine. Actually, blazing fast might be a better word.  But there are many things (primarily software development) that I need to do in Ubuntu instead of Windows.

I feel that it is a driver issue, but I don't even know where to start, since I've always just relied on Ubuntu to install the correct driver automatically for me. Why would the driver be wrong, and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled the problem as Yongchao describe it and found [these instructions](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installation_of_r8168_network_driver).  However, the RTL8168B driver from Realtek is only for linux 2.6, and would require a patch for linux 3.0 (which ships with Oneiric).

However, the same search pulled up [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/853671), which suggested installing the following "backport" module to update the r8169 driver to work correctly.  My steps were as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leannogasawara/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-net-`uname -r`
```

And then reboot.

Once the machine rebooted, the internet poured in like liquid gold.  Thanks to [Yongchao Liu](https://askubuntu.com/users/31791/yongchao-liu) for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The instructions link is down. Thank you for the link to the bug report!

Answer (score 2):

if you search the internet a bit, there is a reason why this is failing. If you do 
`lspci` in the shell. you might see your network interface card is using 8168B. However, if you lsmod, you can see the system load the r8169 driver which is not the correct one.

Just google how to change the r8169 driver back to r8168 and blacklist the r8169. I have the same issue before. But it can be solved.

Comment: Would be great if you are able to describe this process in detail. So the information could be available in one step. :-)